# ¿Como aumentar el zoom de un reporte (FastReport.Web) desde codigo Asp.Net Core C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fastreport

Tengo una aplicación Web Asp.Net Core donde creo reportes con FastReport... y nesecito aumentar el Zoom desde codigo.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

```
 report.Zoom = (150F) ;
```

Intente con esta linea pero me genera un error Interno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SellReport(InfoParametersReport model)
{
    EngineCore Funcion = new EngineCore();
    FastReport.Utils.RegisteredObjects.AddConnection(typeof(MySqlDataConnection));
    FastReport.Web.WebReport report = new FastReport.Web.WebReport();
    InfoFecha F = new InfoFecha();
    F = Funcion.ReportPeriod(model.Month);
    model.FechaInicial = F.FechaInicial;
    model.FechaFinal = F.FechaFinal;
    string frx = string.Empty;
    switch (model.TypeReport)
    {
        case 1:
            frx = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "ReportTemplate", "Invoice.frx");
            ViewBag.Title = "Invoice Report";
            break;
        case 2:
            frx = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "ReportTemplate", "EstadoCuentaGeneral.frx");
            ViewBag.Title = "General Account Statement";
            break;
        case 3:
            frx = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "ReportTemplate", "EstadoCuentaPorCliente.frx");
            ViewBag.Title = "Account Statement for Final Client";
            break;
        case 4:
            frx = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "ReportTemplate", "EstadoCuentaPorLocacion.frx");
            ViewBag.Title = "Account Statement by Location";
            break;
    }
    report.Report.Load(frx);
    MySqlDataConnection conn = new MySqlDataConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = Spartane.Web.Core.Helpers.ConfigurationManager.DefaultConnection;
    conn.CreateAllTables();
    report.Report.Dictionary.Connections.Add(conn);
    report.Report.SetParameterValue("contractNumber", model.ContractNumber);
    report.Report.SetParameterValue("fechaInicial", model.FechaInicial.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
    report.Report.SetParameterValue("fechaFinal", model.FechaFinal.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
    ViewBag.WebReport = report;
    return View("SellReport");
}
```

Comment: ¿No sería mejor aumentar el temaño de fuente?

Comment: Aumentra el tamaño de la fuente no resuelve el problema la idea es que el reporte ocupe mayor parte en la pagina

Comment: En ese caso, hay que diseñar mejor el reporte. No le veo sentido aumentar el zoom

Comment: sino pones esa linea de Zoom el reporte se visualiza correctamente ?

Comment: Si elimino esa linea ...se renderiza perfecto